# How to eliminate the offset for a continued shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I wanted to add a little extra to the last shape in a chain (see image for a better understanding). However, i ran into an unexpected problem, because i thought the (black&red) lines would connect without any vertical offset. So my question is (hopefully) a simple one: how to fix this?

Thx in advance

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        flowEnd/.style={draw, shape=signal, signal from=west, signal to=nowhere},
        flowPast/.style={draw, shape=signal, signal from=west},
        flowStart/.style={draw, shape=signal, signal to=east},
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right,node distance=2mm]
    \node [flowStart,on chain] {Hello};
    \node [flowPast,on chain] {World};
    \node (end) [flowEnd,on chain] {!};
    \draw [red]
    let \p1=(end.south east), \p2=(end.north east) in 
    (\p2) --
    ($ (\p2) + (10mm,0) $) [rounded corners]--
    ($ (\p1) + (10mm,0) $) --
    (\p1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN shapes style definition you should add `outer sep=0pt` and define common `minimum height=...`. Complete, a bit simplified code for your image is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                chains,
                shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{
     base/.style = {draw, shape=signal, on chain, 
                    minimum height=3ex, outer sep=0pt},
  flowEnd/.style = {base, signal from=west, signal to=nowhere},
 flowPast/.style = {base, signal from=west},
flowStart/.style = {base, signal to=east},
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain = going right,
  node distance = 2mm   ]
%
\node [flowStart] {Hello};
\node [flowPast] {World};
\node (end) [flowEnd] {!};
%
\draw[red]
   (end.north east) -- ++ (10mm,0) [rounded corners] |- (end.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thx!